# How to make gridview row to be hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to make my gridview row to be hyperlink -  so basically on mouse over i want to have a cursor hand and highlights on my gridview row. then on click I want to call my another page (summary.aspx?id=1245) -  the id should be get in column 0 of the row..

im using a template field for my gridview
If possible kindly show me in VB.NET code..

thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<asp:hyperlinkfield />` and the the `datanavigateurlformatstring` attribute with such a text like this `datanavigateurlformatstring="details_title.aspx?titleid={0}"`

Comment: See this for sample code: http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/controls/addinghyperlinkfieldstogridview.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - BUt i want to hyperlink all row.. and I dont want to use hyperlink field.. I know it can do in rowdatabound.. but i dont know how